# How to Control "Halo" in Android Seekbar

Tags: android, seekbar

I (finally) have a pretty nice drawable that I am using as a thumb for my SeekBar.  It's, essentially a 20dp dark blue circle inside a 40dp light blue circle inside a 60 dp transparent circle.

However, when I touch the thumb, a "halo" (I'm sure there is a better/real word for this) expands the circle for as long as I'm touching the thumb.  It's pretty big -- maybe up to 80dp -- and in a grayish color.

My question is: how do I control the size of the halo and its color.  (It would be nice to be able to do it in the xml layout rather than programatically with code.)

Here's my drawable ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
            <size android:width="60dp" android:height="60dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary50"/>
            <stroke android:color="@android:color/transparent" android:width="20dp"/>
            <size android:width="40dp" android:height="40dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
            <stroke android:color="@android:color/transparent" android:width="40dp"/>
            <size android:width="20dp" android:height="20dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Here's my seekbar layout

```
<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"
    android:splitTrack="false"
    />
```

Here's what I'm seeing...

[image: SeekBar]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If possible, capture some screenshots of what you are seeing, upload them somewhere, and link to them from your question.

Comment: I've added a screen shot above.